# mongodb find complex

Tags: mongodb

this is my collection structure :

coll{

```
id:...,

..,

fieldA:{

   fieldA1:[

       {

           ...

       }

   ],

   ...,

   fieldA2:[

       {

           text: "ciao",

       },

       {

           text: "hello",

       },

       ...  

   ] 

} 

...
```

}

i want to find the document with for example text="ciao" 
I use the follow:
Db.coll.find({fieldA: { fieldA2: {$elementMatch:{ text:”ciao”} } } }) 
but the result is nothing...
how can I do to do this operation?
thank u very match..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [dot notation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+%28Reaching+into+Objects%29) to refer to the embedded document:

```
db.coll.find({'fieldA.fieldA2': { $elemMatch:{ text:"ciao"} }})
```

Also note that the operator is [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/elemMatch/), not $elementMatch.